# JQ: add nested object with name of top-level key

Tags: jq

In my input in JQ 1.4...

```
{
    "key x": {
        "b": "1"
    },
    "key y": {
        "b": "1"
    }
}
```

...should add new nested objects under each top-level key with the name of its  top-level key. So the result looks like

```
{
    "key x": {
        "a": "key x",
        "b": "1"
    },
    "key y": {
        "a": "key y",
        "b": "1"
    }
}
```

But without using the key names (e.g. ."key x".a="key x") directly, because i dont know during runtime the real key names.

Answer (score 3):

A simple answer would be:

```
with_entries(.value.a = .key)
```

Comment: Thanks, y solution is shorter than my, but in y case y append always the new object at the end, but in my solution I would like to add as the 1st object.

Comment: Hmm, okay. JSON objects are usually processed as unordered data structures, so it shouldn't matter. What's your use case?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, found solution:

```
to_entries  | map( {(.key): ({a: .key}+.value)} ) | add
```

will return

```
{
  "key x": {
    "a": "key x",
    "b": "1"
  },
  "key y": {
    "a": "key y",
    "b": "1"
  }
}
```

to_entries splits to key/value pairs what is much easier to access each key and extend its value by new object.